# Run xpath expression in batch

Tags: java, xml, xpath, batch-processing

We have a lot of xpath expressions that we need to run against a lot of documents and I'd like to speed this up.
Currently, we load document and run all xpaths. In case of having 1000 documents and 1000 xpaths, it is about 1,000,000 runs. I believe every single xpath starts traversing xml from the root node (though I am not sure how it is implemented in libraries). I'd like to make something like batch xpath run, in which just by one xml traversal all the 1000 xpaths would be evaluated. In other words, for 1 document, just one xml traversal is needed to evaluate 1000 xpaths. Is there something like this already implemented & would it even speed up xpath execution?

EDIT:
The only thing I have on input is a list of xpaths and list of xml documents. Since they can be dynamically added/removed by user, I am mainly looking for a solution for grouping xpaths in runtime (not to do it in pre-configuration, even though it may help to speed up the framework-provided xpaths).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting the data in an XML database such as BaseX or eXist. These products build indexes which will be used to speed up the query execution. There's a cost to build the index, but over 1000 queries it should be saved many times over.

Comment: Thank you, these databases look really promising. I think this is a framework we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Can you organise your xpaths in a hierarchy?
For example, instead of running

- `//a/b/x`
- `//a/b/y`
- `//a/b/z`

Could you pre-process the xpaths to group together common prefixes such that you run `x`, `y` and `z` over the result of `//a/b`? I can only assume that running these 4 xpaths (`//a/b`, `x`, `y`, `z`) is quicker than running the 3 xpaths above. Also, if `//a/b` fails, you can avoid running the child xpaths.

I could imagine some config like this:

```
<xpaths>
    <xpathparent value="//a/b">
        <xpath value="x" handler="xHandler" />
        <xpath value="y" handler="yHandler" />
        <xpath value="z" handler="zHandler" />
    </xpathparent>
<xpaths>
```

Comment: this is definitely a good thought, however xpaths are really dynamically changing in our environment. In the framework, user is able to disable some xpaths from happening or register his own xpaths. In other words, it is possible that most of the common-pattern xpaths don't know about each other because they are defined in other place/ by different user. I will edit the question to cover this scenario

Comment: Might need to be automated then. Perhaps an automated process which splits all xpaths on `/` and arranges into a hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, something like this. Don't you know if such functionality would be provided by some framework or is this needed to by implemented? I think this will have a lot of edge cases ( //a vs /root/a, attributes etc.)

Comment: `//a` is logically different to `/root/a` so I don't see any other option but to execute both (and group differently in the hierarchy). And no, I haven't heard of a framework to do this

Comment: Maybe. However if my assumption is right and in order to run xpath `//a` processor needs to access every single node in a document, why not to use this time spent traversing to check if there is also `//b` or `//c` ? Maybe I am wrong and `//a` doesn't need to traverse whole document.

Comment: Yes, `//a` and `//b` will both traverse the whole document. Keep in mind that traversing the document once and executing `//a` and `//b` for each line is the same as traversing the document twice (once for `//a` then again for `//b`). Both have the same complexity. For 1000 lines in a document it's 2000 executions. Since it's a DOM operation the model is in memory so extra IO not required for 2 traversals. Thee real win with my hierarchy suggestion is you can avoid running child xpaths if a parent is not found